# Can't update to 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to update to ubuntu  18.04 LTS using terminal and following [these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-update-ubuntu-packages-on-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

```
$ sudo apt update
```

this command ran ok

then

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

command gives me the following error:

```
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Please can you help?

Comment: as we can see in the error message, the package `linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic` want to be reinstalled, but isn't found in ppa; make a search with `apt search linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic` -> if output, use `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic --reinstall`, if no output, then you might search another ppa which got this package, or delete it

Comment: sudo apt search linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic gave me this "linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic/now 4.4.0-134.160 i386 [installed,local]
  (none) I believe this is no output. I tried the second command anyway but got the same error message. Please can you point me to a ppa which got this package?

Comment: try using `apt autoremove && apt autoclean && sudo init 6` and then `apt-get install linux-headers* `.

Comment: Also I tried command "sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic" and got this "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."
Sorry i do not understand how to format my text properly

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I got this "$ sudo apt autoremove && apt autoclean && sudo init 6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. ~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: what the output said if you type `uname -a`

Comment: before you try upgrade your system to 18.04, what the kernel used before it.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri :Linux rakam-HP-Mini-110-4100 4.4.0-133-generic #159-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 07:26:31 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: you can't find that archive cause this packages belong to Canonical team. check [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic). i suggest to try `apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: it gives me strictly the same :Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: what are you using kernel team distribution now sir?

Comment: It is Xubuntu 16.04; $ uname -r
4.4.0-133-generic